# How to get ALL FieldIds in a Podio app (even when some fields are empty)

Tags: c#, podio

Podio API seems to only let you loop through field's that contain values. Is there some way of doing this that I've missed? This is what should work but doesn't...

```
foreach (var field in itemCurrent.Fields)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get empty fields in GetItem call. Only fields with value are given for the GetItem using itemid. To get all the fields you need to call GetApp using app id, Then you can loop through the fields in the app and get value from item using the appfield external id

Comment: I see. Thank you.